# "For some time" vs "For some times"

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between

> He has been working here for some time.

and

> He has been working here for some times.

Is it correct to say *for sometimes*? I seached a lot, but I did not find an answer at all.

Comment: 'for some times' is just not correct. They are not multiple times, there is just one measured length…. 'some time'. It implies more than a short time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use countable nouns?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/how-to-use-countable-nouns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In:

> He has been working here **for some time**.

*time* as used here means one time of unspecified length, and does not refer to multiple times. So plural "times" would not be used.

As for [***sometimes***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sometimes), this is an abverb so you would not used it by itself in a prepositional phrase.
So you can't say:

> He has been working here **for sometimes**.

but you can say:

> He has been working here **sometimes**.

however the meaning here is various unspecified times, which is different from the original phrase, which meant one time of unspecified length.